# Is econometrics becoming inward-looking?

Tags: econometrics, macroeconomics

Michael Wickens claims in his (generally interesting) article and speech *How did we get to where we are now? Refections on 50 years of macroeconomic and financial econometrics* from 2014, that

> "Econometric research has become increasingly inward-looking over the years, and as a result, its influence on macroeconomics has diminished".

Can we see this in data, if we by the "subject" mean published research? Would it for example be true that articles in macroeconomic research journals to a lesser extent than before cite articles in econometric journals?

The article can be dowloaded at: http://www.york.ac.uk/media/economics/documents/discussionpapers/2014/1417.pdf

I have edited this question to make it easier to answer it, after some criticism.

Comment: Despite being an interesting question this will probably be closed as primarily opinion based or due the tangential relation with statistics.

Comment: You can help the discussion by giving a link to the full text of that generally interesting article. On this site (which isn't a forum, BTW), you will be more likely to find statisticians and data scientists than econometricians, although at some point the econometrics beta site was merged with this one.